# Java, как правильно забрать значение по ключу из Json?

Tags: java, json

Json имеет вид:

```
{  
   "cover":"blabla.jpg",
   "content":[  
      {  
         "article":"article_text",
         "document":"document_text"
      }
   ]
}
```

Получить значение поля "cover" я могу легко

```
JSONObject json = new JsonObject(jsonStr); //jsonStr - мой json в видео строки    
json.get("cover");
```

А вот как добраться до значения "article"?

Comment: ну видимо json.getJsonArray("content").get(0).getString("article");

Comment: @pavel пробовал так, ошибка, `.get(0)` возвращает строку, у нее нет метода `.getString()`

Comment: а если вместо get getJSONObject(0) написать?

Comment: @pavel спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для получения массива объектов есть метод `getJSONArray(название)`. Для получения из него объекта `getJSONObject(номер)` , количество элементов `length()`.

Всё вместе

```
json.getJSONArray("content").getJSONObject(0).getString("article");
```

Comment: спасибо, у меня обёртка была написана вот её и скопировал случайно)

Comment: Если структура json известна заранее, лучше сделать класс под эту структуру и десериализовать json в этот класс. Такой код намного легче читается, с ним удобней работать и легче рефакторить.